# Mudar a cor de apenas uma das barras/colunas do gráfico gerado no PPTX - Apache Poi

Tags: java, gráfico, apache-poi, powerpoint

Estou trabalhando com o `Apache Poi v4.1.2` no `Java` para geração de arquivos `.pptx`, exibição de slides no `PowerPoint`. Basicamente estou usando o `Apache Poi` para gerar slides com gráficos, até aí tudo bem, estou conseguindo gerar os slides com os gráficos e tudo, mas chegou uma demanda pra mim que é a possibilidade de alterar as cores das barras/colunas do gráfico para cores customizadas. Eu ja consegui fazer ele mudar as cores do gráfico por `série`, ou seja, todas as barras de "tal" `série` tem a cor alterada para uma customizada, o problema é q tem casos onde eu preciso mudar a cor de uma única barra/coluna, ou seja, mudar a cor por categoria talvez ou algo mais específico, mas eu não consegui achar uma forma de fazer isso, nem em minhas pesquisas eu achei algo que me ajude, alguém pode me dar uma luz e me ajudar?

código q estou usando para settar a cor customizada:

```
final XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0 })); // usando a cor preta como exemplo
final XDDFChartData.Series series = this.getElementGraph().getSeries(0); // pegando a primeira série
// o this.getElementGraph() retorna um XDDFChartData
XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
if (properties == null) {
    properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
}
properties.setFillProperties(fill);
series.setShapeProperties(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu código acima, você pode substituir as linhas:

```
XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
if (properties == null) {
    properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
}
properties.setFillProperties(fill);
series.setShapeProperties(properties);
```

por uma simples linha:

```
series.setFillProperties(fill);
```

já que seu código reproduz o código do método acima.

Quanto à sua pergunta, faltava, de fato até hoje, a possibilidade de alterar individualmente um determinado ponto do gráfico.

Será possível assim que for publicada a versão com a alteração sugerida em https://github.com/apache/poi/pull/228

Passará a ser possível chamar assim:

```
XDDFDataPoint point = series.getDataPoint(2);
point.setFillProperties(fill);
```

Será possível também alterar o marcador no caso de `ScatterChart` ou `LineChart`, assim como a explosão no caso de `PieChart`.